# Using Google Calendar API V3 with .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, google-api, .net-3.5, google-calendar-api

I am using a Web application which uses .Net 3.5 framework. It uses the Google calendar API V1.

When searched in google forums it was found that the Google calendar API V1 & V2 are deprecated and should use V3.

Google Calendar API V3 platform support is .NET Framework 4 and 4.5

So should our application be upgraded to .NET framework 4 or 4.5 ?

Or is there is any solution for using google calendar API in .Net 3.5 framework ?

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** Google Calendar API V3 platform support is .NET Framework 4 and 4.5
**Anwser / comment :** This is incorrect the Google Calendar API V3 is a rest API and supports any programing language that can do a HTTP Post or HTTP Get.  The Current version of the Google .Net Client library how ever only supports .Net Framework 4 and 4.5.

1. [Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)
2. [Client library on GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client)

**Question:** So should our application be upgraded to .NET framework 4 or 4.5 ?
**Anwser :** Yes if you want to use Googles client library, which I recommend. You should upgrade to .net Framework 4 or 4.5.   I would go with 4.5 if you can.

**Question:** Is there is any solution for using google calendar API in .Net 3.5.
 framework ?
**Anwser:**  Yes you can code the whole thing yourself like I said its just HTTP Posts and HTTP Gets.  The hardest part of this will be the authentication, but you should be able to rip some of the code from the client library.  I have a couple of old tutorials I made back when I was doing this with the Google Analytics API.  The idea is the same.

1. Old tutorial on how to do it hasn't been updated in ages sorry. [Google APIs and Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/)
2. [Google Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Comment: Amazing response.  I will be attempting to re-create your tutorial for accessing Google Calendar.  Thanks

Comment: If you need any help let me know. I am also working on a class I like to call Google.apis.light.   its a light version of the auth in the current client library.   works with .net framework 2.0 and up.   Its a work in progress I intend to open source it soon.

Comment: I've successfully recreated your tutorial in vb.net.  If you like, I can share the code with you to add to your C# tutorial.

Comment: I will do you one better.  Contact me: http://www.daimto.com/contact/ we can turn it into a tutorial all its own.  I have had a number of people requesting that.  My VB is rusty.